# ​IMAP produce MessagingException / MessageRemovedIOException on Office 365

Tags: spring, office365, imap

I try to get some messages with IMAP and Spring IntegrationFlow. The following code is working well (since 4 years) until the mailbox moved to Office 365.

```java
return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter(imapMailReceiver).get(),
                        e -> e.autoStartup(true)
                                .poller(Pollers.cron(properties.getCron(), TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"))
                                        
                                        .maxMessagesPerPoll(MAILS_PER_POLL)
                                        .errorHandler(mailReceiverErrorHandler("imapMailReceiver", param, portefeuille))
                                )
                )
                
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, m -> loggerMessageMail(m, "IMAP"))
                .channel(c -> mailChannel)
                .get();
```

Now, we sometimes get this exception:

```
Exception: failure occurred while polling for mail; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while copying message; nested exception is: com.sun.mail.util.MessageRemovedIOException
```

After some research, this exception occurs when your try to get an expunged message. Let's consider that I can't change the Office 365 server or do some action on it (like clean expunged messages...)

Is there a way to filter on the IntegrationFlow those messages to avoid this exception ?

Comment: Fix: Wrong copy/paste code (was the POP3 version, not IMAP)

Comment: You can't filter in principle. The messages are expunged after you learn about their existence but before you try to access them. That shouldn't be a very long time, in fact I expect the time between checking for existence and accessing will be roughly as long. So in your case I'd advise either handling the exception when it occurs or (perhaps better) looking at why those messages are expunged.